# How can I train a binary classifier to find a logo?

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning

So I'm trying to contruct a simple binary classifier.

**Problem:** Classify an image as containing the apple logo, or not.

I'd like it to be distortion, color, size and rotationally invariant. I'm sure that Classify[] should be able to handle this problem given the data. I have a set of positively and negatively labeled images you can [download from this link](http://we.tl/WNdG1vd5I8), it's a file called PositiveAndNegativeAppleData.zip (about 20 mb).

Here's how to get my code going:

```
dir =(*path to dir containing unzipped folders*);

ndir = FileNameJoin[{dir, "negative"}];
pdir = FileNameJoin[{dir, "positive"}];

nfiles = FileNameJoin[{ndir, #}] & /@ Import[ndir];
pfiles = FileNameJoin[{pdir, #}] & /@ Import[pdir];

CloseKernels[]; LaunchKernels[16];
negative = ParallelMap[Import, nfiles];

positive = ParallelMap[Import, pfiles];

trainingData = <|"Apple" -> positive, "None" -> negative|>;

c = Classify[trainingData, 
  Method -> {"SupportVectorMachine", 
    "KernelType" -> "RadialBasisFunction", 
    "MulticlassMethod" -> "OneVersusAll"}, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]
```

I still haven't been able to obtain a ClassifierFunction with high accuracy. I'd really appreciate some insight here, seems like a standard problem.

Comment: Why do you call it standard problem? There's no universal method to find high accuracy classifiers from image data (eg partial fingerprints matching - recently a $100k Innocentive challenge, ppl playing frisbee etc).

Comment: One of the problem is your image sizes. In your training set negative images is considerably larger then positive. It can give undesirable dependence on the image size. If I understand correctly, the main problem is *find* the place of the logo in the big image. It is not what `Classify` do. May be a combination with `MorphologicalComponents` will give you better results. P.S. I'm not a professional in this area.

Comment: Can you offer the datasets again?

Comment: I don't have them anymore, just use flickr-32 instead

Answer (score 4):

Change a bit code, also are you sure `<|"Apple" -> negative, "None" -> positive|>` or did I misunderstood the problem? Anyways this seems logical (works same efficiently without **ConformImages** but I just wanted to feature it):

```
dir =(*path to dir containing unzipped folders*);

ndir = FileNameJoin[{dir, "negative"}];
pdir = FileNameJoin[{dir, "positive"}];

nfiles = Import[ndir <> "/*.png"];
pfiles = Import[pdir <> "/*.png"];

negative = ConformImages[nfiles, 200];
positive = ConformImages[pfiles, 200];

$train = 100;

trainingData = <|"Apple" -> positive[[;;$train]], "None" -> negative[[;;$train]]|>;
testingData = <|"Apple" -> positive[[$train+1;;]], "None" -> negative[[$train+1;;]]|>;

c = Classify[trainingData, 
   Method -> {"SupportVectorMachine", 
     "KernelType" -> "RadialBasisFunction", 
     "MulticlassMethod" -> "OneVersusAll"}, 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"];

Magnify[{#, c[#]} & /@ 
Flatten[{RandomSample[positive[[$trainSize + 1 ;;]], 10], 
  RandomSample[negative[[$trainSize + 1 ;;]], 10]}] // Transpose // Grid, 0.5]
```

[image]

```
cm = ClassifierMeasurements[c, testingData];

cm["Accuracy"]
```

> 0.796954

```
cm["ConfusionMatrixPlot"]
```

[image]

**Response to Answer**

Thanks Vitalyi, great start, yes 79% is not terrible! Unfortunately, this is not working for any images that have real backgrounds. For example:
[image]

What do we need to to to make the detector more robust to the logo signal? This is the heart of the problem!

Comment: It is interesting. But what about images being out of the training set? Is it possible to recognize something new?

Comment: @ybeltukov yes, I updated the code to show that. Got even better results - accidentally of course.

Comment: Wow, incredible!

Comment: Right, I had the positive and negative reversed...

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov Ok so 79% accuracy is not so great, how can I do better? Also the classifier is not very good on finding images in the wild, see my edits.

Comment: SIFT + SVM is the classical solution to this problem, I was hoping `Classify[]` would be at least as strong.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov would it help for me to compile a separate more difficult test set with the types of images this fails on?

Comment: You may check this answer. Mainly, you may create codebook+histogram explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048891/training-of-svm-classifier-using-sift-features Also, you may use ImageKeypoints with option "Descriptor" with surf descriptor instead of sift.

Comment: @M.R. your training set is very small and not diverse. To have a more extended discussion you can try asking on http://community.wolfram.com where developers are hanging out - I am not really a specilist in the field.

Comment: @s.s.o it's unclear how `ImageKeypoints[]` and `Classify[]` would work together here

Comment: @M.R did you check the link its explained step by step in the 2. Answer. There's also other related links there. Dont expect 90 persent accuracy.  80 isreasonable result.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov Ok reposted to Wolfram Community [http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/428192?p_p_auth=0qWppOXM].